# how to resolve error while redirecting from one page to another in zen-cart

Tags: php, redirect, zen-cart

I want to update a value of database while changing the options in the dropdown list. After upadation ctrl redirect back to the orders page. Now the updation is working properly but it couldn't back to orders page. I'm using the following code for that.

code in orders.php

```
<select name="order_status" onchange="update(this.value,<?php echo $row['orders_id'];?>)">
    <option value="1" <?php if($row['orders_status']=='1'){ ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?>>In process</option>
    <option value="2"<?php if($row['orders_status']=='2'){ ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?>>Processed</option>
    <option value="3"<?php if($row['orders_status']=='3'){ ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?>>Dispatched</option>
    </select>

            <script>
            function update(vals,order){
                window.location="index.php?main_page=orders&val="+vals+"&id="+order;
            }
            </script>


<?php
if(($_REQUEST['id']) && ($_REQUEST['val'])){

    $manufacturers = $db->Execute("update orders set orders_status = '{$_REQUEST['val']}'
                                    where orders_id ='{$_REQUEST['id']}'");

if($manufacturers == '1'){
zen_redirect(zen_href_link('orders', '', $request_type));
}
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code:

1. You have serious SQL Injection vulnerabilities in your code. You need to sanitize your inputs before using them in a database query. If someone discovers your page and tries to use rogue inputs they could do SERIOUS damage to your database.
2. You can't use a database-object as an operand when comparing against a string value.

   ```
   if($manufacturers == '1'){
     zen_redirect(zen_href_link('orders', '', $request_type));
   }
   ```

You could probably replace that with just the zen_redirect line, without the if() statement, since you'll do the redirect regardless.

1. And then there's the whole issue of why you're doing administrative update tasks on storefront pages which don't have administration privileges in the first place.